# Accessing values of object properties in PowerShell

Tags: object, powershell

I'm going through an array of objects and I can display the objects fine.

```
$obj
```

displays each object in my foreach loop fine.
I'm trying to access the object fields and their values.
This  code also works fine:

```
$obj.psobject.properties
```

To just see the names of each object's fields, I do this:

```
$obj.psobject.properties | % {$_.name}
```

which also works fine.

When I try to access the values of those field by doing this:

```
$obj.psobject.properties | % {$obj.$_.name}
```

nothing is returned or displayed.

This is done for diagnostic purposes to see whether I can access the values of the fields.
The main dilemma is that I cannot access a specific field's value. I.e.

```
$obj."some field"
```

does not return a value even though I have confirmed that "some field" has a value.

This has baffled me. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Once you iterate over the properties inside the foreach, they become available via `$_` (current object symbol). Just like you printed the names of the properties with `$_.Name`, using `$_.Value` will print their values:

```
$obj.psobject.properties | % {$_.Value}
```

Comment: +1. I suspected something as obvious as this, so went ahead to check, but you posted your answer by the time I came back. As a side note to OP - you could have discovered the `Value` property by doing this: `$obj.psobject.properties | gm`.

Comment: I did that for diagnostic purposes to see whether I could access the values of the fields. However when I try to access the value of a certain field that I know exists, like $obj."certain field", nothing is returned

Answer (score 9):

Operator precedence interprets that in the following way:

```
($obj.$_).Name
```

which leads to nothing because you want

```
$obj.($_.Name)
```

which will first evaluate the name of a property and then access it on `$obj`.

Comment: I thought of that as I usually incorporate parentheses for this exact reason. Still does not yield what I want.

Comment: That's weird. A simple test for me was `$a = gci | select -f 1; $a.psobject.properties|%{$_.Name + "`t`t" + $a.($_.Name)}` which works just fine.

Comment: Another way is with quotes:  `$obj."$($_.name)"`

Comment: @x0n: That's a little overkill, though, to use a double-quoted string with a sub-expression when you can just use parentheses (or the sub-expression without the surrounding string).

Answer (score 9):

You don't have to iterate over all properties if you just need the value of one of them:

```
$obj.psobject.properties["foo"].value
```

Comment: Whhat is "bla"?