# How do you get the name field of a JSON object in Powershell if you don't know it?

Tags: json, powershell, powershell-3.0

I have this JSON file:

```
{
    "CARD_MODEL_TITLE": "OWNER'S MANUAL",
    "CARD_MODEL_SUBTITLE": "Configure your download",
    "CARD_MODEL_SELECT": "Select Model",
    "CARD_LANG_TITLE": "Select Language",
    "CARD_LANG_DEVICE_LANG": "Your device",
    "CARD_YEAR_TITLE": "Select Model Year",
    "CARD_YEAR_LATEST": "(Latest)",
    "STEPS_MODEL": "Model",
    "STEPS_LANGUAGE": "Language",
    "STEPS_YEAR": "Model Year",
    "BUTTON_BACK": "Back",
    "BUTTON_NEXT": "Next",
    "BUTTON_CLOSE": "Close"
}
```

And the syntax I use to convert it to a JSON object in Powershell is this one:

```
$json = (Get-Content "jsonfile.json") -join "`n" | ConvertFrom-Json
```

The thing is that I want to edit the *value* of each pair *name/value*, but the *name* field may vary in other files, and since I want a single script for every file this has to be generic.

How do I get the *name* field of a pair *name/value* without knowing the *name* field beforehand? Or in other words, I want a kind of: `foreach ($i in $json)`

Thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use $json.psobject.properties.name after it's converted:

```
@'
   {
    "CARD_MODEL_TITLE": "OWNER'S MANUAL",
    "CARD_MODEL_SUBTITLE": "Configure your download",
    "CARD_MODEL_SELECT": "Select Model",
    "CARD_LANG_TITLE": "Select Language",
    "CARD_LANG_DEVICE_LANG": "Your device",
    "CARD_YEAR_TITLE": "Select Model Year",
    "CARD_YEAR_LATEST": "(Latest)",
    "STEPS_MODEL": "Model",
    "STEPS_LANGUAGE": "Language",
    "STEPS_YEAR": "Model Year",
    "BUTTON_BACK": "Back",
    "BUTTON_NEXT": "Next",
    "BUTTON_CLOSE": "Close"
   }
'@ | set-content jsonfile.json

$json = (Get-Content "jsonfile.json" -Raw) | ConvertFrom-Json

$json.psobject.properties.name

CARD_MODEL_TITLE
CARD_MODEL_SUBTITLE
CARD_MODEL_SELECT
CARD_LANG_TITLE
CARD_LANG_DEVICE_LANG
CARD_YEAR_TITLE
CARD_YEAR_LATEST
STEPS_MODEL
STEPS_LANGUAGE
STEPS_YEAR
BUTTON_BACK
BUTTON_NEXT
BUTTON_CLOSE
```

You can also eliminate the `-join` by using the `-Raw` switch with `Get-Content`

Comment: can you loop through the properties names?