# In pwsh, how do you use a script block like {$_.UserId} to get some information from an object?

Tags: powershell, powershell-core

I have an object that contains a field named PKBlock which accepts a script value

```
$o.PKBlock = { return $_.UserId }
```

or

```
$o.PKBlock = { return $_.GroupId + $_.ResourceId }
```

I would like to pass an object (shown here in json)

```
{
    "UserId":"aodpkjpw92kjd",
    "GroupId":"90djd0223djd",
    "ResourceId":"012ekkkk023"
}
```

How do I execute the script block and get the return value?

I have tried the following (where $record is the object as an object):

```
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock $o.PKBlock -InputObject $record
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock $o.PKBlock -ArgumentList $record
$record | Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock $o.PKBLock
```

Comment: Here ya go: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16575419/powershell-retrieve-json-object-by-field-value . This should answer your question

Comment: @AbrahamZinala much appreciated, but the link is telling how to get values and does not contain any information regarding script blocks that I am seeing.   I do not believe this applies to my question.   I am wanting to use a script block to generate a primary key from an object programatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the unnamed automatic variable in a scriptblock is `$args`. First argument is `$args[0]`, second is `$args[1]`, etc. All arguments are contained in just `$args`

You can invoke the scriptblock a few different ways.

```
&  # call operator, new child scope

.  # call operator, calling scope. Also used for "dot sourcing"

Invoke-Command
```

Next issue is if you want to access the json properties by name you'll need to make that an object. Probably the easiest is `ConvertFrom-Json`. Once you have those two corrected, any of these should work.

```
$o.PKBlock = { return $args[0].userid } 

$json = @'
{
    "UserId":"aodpkjpw92kjd",
    "GroupId":"90djd0223djd",
    "ResourceId":"012ekkkk023"
}
'@ | ConvertFrom-Json
```

Now call it

```
& $o.PKBlock $json
```

or

```
. $o.PKBlock $json
```

or

```
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock $o.PKBlock -ArgumentList $json
```

You could also provide named parameters for your scriptblock

```
$o.PKBlock = {
    Param($object) return $object.userid
}
```

Call it the same way.

**EDIT**

`$_` or `$PSItem` is automatic variable for any number of cmdlets. If you really want to use that vs args/named parameters, you can pass into `Foreach-Object`

```
$json | ForEach-Object {. $o.PKBlock $_}
```

or

```
$json | ForEach-Object {. $o.PKBlock $psitem}
```

Comment: Much appreciated, that fixed my issue.   I was hoping to use $_ and inputobject but this will get my task done.